# Modelling a multinominal logistic regression over time series

Tags: time-series, logistic, multinomial-distribution

I'm pretty new to statistical analyses. For a research project I want to identify which are the major factors that influence the adoption of electric vehicles in one country. Over a time of 10 years (2007-2016) I have 4 metric Response Variables (Market Share in new registrations for Benzin(1), Diesel(2), Hybrid(3) and Electric(4) vehicles) and 13 X-Variables (Price (1,2,3,4), Operation Cost (1,2,3,4), Infrastructure (1,2,3,4) and Per Capita Income in the country. I thought a Multinominal Logistic Regression Model could be used to identify the impact of those Variables on the Market Share of each technology, but I'm struggling with the setup of a model in Excel. Therefore I was wondering if Multinominal Logistic Regression is the right approach for that problem or if there is a better way to identify the influencing factors.

[image]

Comment: I would't do such a project in excel ... Look for choice modelling (search this site). Multinomial logit could be a start, in addition, look into multinomial probit (there is a R package MNP)